# Are there any Known Space works I should read before Man-Kzin Wars?

Tags: suggested-order, larry-niven, known-space, man-kzin-wars

Are there any works set in [Known Space Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_Space#Stories_in_Known_Space) that should be read before Man-Kzin wars series?

Please note the "should" - I am including works that aren't strictly speaking necessary to "get" the Man-Kzin Wars, but - if read previously - would enhance the understanding or enjoyment of them.

If the answer is specific to individual Man-Kzin Wars books/stories, even better.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend reading the first two *Ringworld* novels prior to beginning the Man-Kzin Wars series. Although *Ringworld* and *Ringworld Engineers* take place after the Man-Kzin wars, they introduce you to the interspecies conflict between Man and Kzin in such a way that the Man-Kzin Wars series becomes a "must read".

(I also suggest reading the *Ringworld* prequel *Protector*, but it isn't an absolutely necessary read in order for you to to enjoy M-K W)

Answer (score 4):

Caveat: I've only read the first M-K Wars book and maybe a few stories from the 2nd one.

Assuming you mean "If I haven't read any Known Space works..." then I'd start with the older Known Space short story collections, "Tales of Known Space" and "Neutron Star."  Although Ringworld and Ringworld Engineers give a retrospective overview of the M-K Wars, I'd start with the older short stories because they include the first 3 Kzinti stories (as I recall... I'd have to double-check) and they set the scene: they give a feel for how Niven had originally envisioned Known Space.

Answer (score 3):

To get a feeling for the pre-war pacifist Earth culture, you might want to check out [Flatlander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatlander_%28short_story_collection%29). You don't really need it to appreciate the MKW series though.

[image: Flatlander]

There are recurring characters and sequels within the series, so read the MKW books in publication order.